# Container queries with webpack css modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, postcss, css-modules

I am trying to use css container queries and css modules in a webpack project. This config looks something like this:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test:   /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader'
  }
```

and a postcss config like this:

```
const nested = require('postcss-nested');
const vars = require('postcss-simple-vars');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const containerQueries = require('cq-prolyfill/postcss-plugin');
module.exports = [
  containerQueries,
  vars({ variables: require('./src/common/vars') }),
  nested,
  autoprefixer
];
```

I want to be able to get this class to work:

```
.card-list:container(width >= 100px) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

And be able to import 'card-list' into my components.

However, this doesn't seem to work. I haven't been able to find anything online about this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ausi/cq-prolyfill/blob/master/docs/usage.md
You should add `cq-prolyfill.min.js` to your bundle. Postcss plugin just converts `:container` syntax to valid css selectors:

```
/* before */
.element:container(width >= 10px) {
    color: red;
}

/*after
.element.\:container\(width\>\=10px\) {
    color: red;
}
```

`cq-prolyfill.min.js` adds resize event that toggles this classes on elements